# How to generate report for integration tests using mvn site command

Tags: maven, unit-testing, integration-testing, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

I have some Unit Tests (classes *Test.java in src/test folder, executed by Surefire Plugin) and some other Integration Tests (classes *IT.java in src/it folder, executed by Failsafe Plugin): .xml and .txt reports are correctly generated in folders target/surfire-reports and target/failsafe-reports when I run
 `mvn install` .

Furthermore I would like to have html reports: I think that the best solution should be to use `mvn site`, in order to have also CSS files.
However, now only unit tests are executed, so only target/surfire-reports are generated and obviously the only html doc that is generated is about unit tests. 
POM snippet below:

```
<build>
...
   <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      ...
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      ...
      <goal>integration-test</goal>
      <goal>verify</goal>
      ...
   </plugin>
   <plugin> 
      // definition of build helper maven plugin for the registration 
      // of the src/it folder
   </plugin>
...
</build>

<reporting>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
         <groupId>org.maven.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.19.1</version>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Clearly, `mvn site` doesn't execute integration-test goal, but how can I solve?
PS: A silly solution is to run mvn site after mvn install (without a clean), but I would like to have something smarter.

Answer (score 0):

> There are three built-in build lifecycles: default, clean and site.
> The default lifecycle handles your project deployment, the clean
> lifecycle handles project cleaning, while the site lifecycle handles
> the creation of your project's site documentation.

- In **default** lifecycle you'll find "**verify**" step which is the one that will run you integration tests
- In **site** lifecycle, you'll have your site execution.

So the command should be :

```
mvn clean verify site
```

(always clean your workspace unless special requirements)

[Maven Build Lifecycle Basics](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#build-lifecycle-basics)

Answer (score 0):

Use JaCoCo plugin in your pom adn just run `mvn clean verify` command. It is open source and very easy to implement.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

add this in your pom.xml. It will generate reports in `target/site/jacoco` directory. if you want to integrate it with SonarQube it is very easy to setup add few params and run command `mvn sonar:sonar`. for more details: https://medium.com/backend-habit/generate-codecoverage-report-with-jacoco-and-sonarqube-ed15c4045885